# Diagnosing Windows 7 Start Menu search delay

Tags: windows-7, search, start-menu

When I enter a search term into my WIndows 7 Start Menu search bar, it invariably takes 20 seconds before returning any results.

[image]

I don't understand why this is taking so long. What can I make the search return results faster and reduce the delay in returning obvious search results?

For example, I probably open notepad twenty times a day and I think that this result should be returned and load instantly upon typing `note[Enter]` whereas I currently type `notepad{wait 20 seconds}[Enter]`

Comment: What about the 2nd time of doing that, or any second search, within say 30 seconds of doing it the first time?  A few hard disks waking back up can take 5-15 seconds.   Windows 7 search fun has created an even larger market for 3rd party replacements, you could try a few, and never look back.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/9R3Ehbs3

Comment: Rebuilding Index may help you, because by default, search locations include start menu search. This can be done by `Control panel - Indexing Options`. I had the same issue, and I rebuilt the index , it worked fine.

Answer (score 4):

This issue was resolved by testing each item in `Control Panel>Indexing Options>Modify` and removing an entry that was very slow to respond.

The offending folder was `Google Drive`, which was very slow to respond both in Explorer and when searched via Start Menu. Now I have removed this from the Indexing I no longer have an absurd delay.

Comment: I think it's because the location is within `My Documents` and the `Google Drive` folder has a large amount of information that regularly changes (hence indexing is often out of date and/or broken)

Comment: How did you find which entry is the slow one?

Comment: @TomášZato I simply tested using binary chop on all the indexed locations; the slow down disappeared once I removed the offending item.